# Add transparency only on a part of image - in odd rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-lists

Is it possible to make every second row background a 50% transparent in a list?
I have something like that:

```
<div style="backgroung-image: url('bg.png')">
<ul>
<li>one</li>
<li>two</li>
<li>three</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

and then i want to have a partly white rows on each second row, but still want to see a background image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**`nth-child()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) selector to target every other `li`.

- For the odd rows provide `odd` or `2n+1` as the parameter.
- For the even rows provide `even` or `2n` as the parameter.

```css
ul, li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

ul {
  background-image: url('https://unsplash.it/1200x100?image=75');
}

li {
  color: white;
}

li:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.5 );
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
  <li>four</li>
  <li>five</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

`li:nth-child(2n)` will select every 2nd `li`.

```css
li:nth-child(2n) {
  opacity:0.5;
}
```

```html
<div style="backgroung-image: url('bg.png')">
<ul>
<li>one</li>
<li>two</li>
<li>three</li>
<li>four</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

to target every second element you can use the `nth` selector

```
li:nth-child(2n) {
background: red;
opacity: 0.5;
}
```